# Python - Use a variable as a list name

Tags: python

I have this code in python.

```
import sys
list1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
list2 = [1, 2, 3]

myarg = sys.argv[1]
print len(myarg)
```

I will run this script from command line like this

```
python script.py list1
```

So I need a way to make the len work with the list instead of the variable, I just want to give the name of the list in the var.

I know for this example I can do

```
if myarg == "list1":
    print len(list1)
else if myarg == "list2"
    print len(list2)
```

But I have 13 lists on my script and I need a way to refer to them by the name I give on the command line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While this is entirely possible in Python, it's not needed. The best solution here is to not do this, have a dictionary instead.

```
import sys

lists = {
    "list1": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "list2": [1, 2, 3],
}

myarg = sys.argv[1]
print len(lists[myarg])
```

You note you have 13 lists in your script - where you have lots of similar data (or data that needs to be handled in a similar way), it's a sign you want a data structure, rather than flat variables. It will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is possible, and thought @Lattyware's answer is the correct one, this is how you **could** do it:

```
import sys
list1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
list2 = [1, 2, 3]

myarg = sys.argv[1]

print len(globals().get(myarg, []))
```

If it prints `0`, then you have a bad argument on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't, but if you really want/have to do this, you can use `globals()`:

```
print len(globals()[myarg])
```

First make sure `myarg` is the name of a declared variable: `if myarg in globals(): ...`