# Making a list value become the variable for a list

Tags: python, list, variables

I am having some problems. I have lists within lists that looks something like this:

```
list = [['bread', 0, 5, 2], ['pasta', 2, 8, 9], ['onion', 3, 6, 12]]
```

So if:

```
list[0] = ['bread', 0, 5, 2]
```

Is there away I can use the first value in each list (i.e 'bread') to become the variable for that list.

What I want in the end is:

```
bread = ['bread', 0, 5, 2]
```

I am new to python so please explain things carefully or I won't understand what you are saying. Also, the list structure is the way it is set up so I can't change it, or at least, hoping not to.

Comment: umm... `bread = list[0]`?

Comment: Broken record I know, but don't use `list` as a variable name in Python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Use a variable as a list name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324465/python-use-a-variable-as-a-list-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to do this. Use a dictionary:

```
>>> lst = [['bread', 0, 5, 2], ['pasta', 2, 8, 9], ['onion', 3, 6, 12]]
>>> d = {lst[0][0] : lst[0]}
{'bread': ['bread', 0, 5, 2]}
```

But if you insist...

```
>>> locals()[lst[0][0]] = lst[0]
>>> bread
['bread', 0, 5, 2]
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals):

> Note The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

---

Also, `list` is a built-in type. Please don't name lists that.

Comment: I havn't I was just using it as an example

Comment: @Danrex: Don't do that either!