# How to iterate through paired values, and how to name a variable from the list you are using?

Tags: python, list, variables, iteration

I have some code here I am having issues with:

```
items = [["item1", 5, 10, 8, 6], ["item2", 4, 6, 3, 9]]
mean = [5, 5, 5, 5]
for x in items[0]:
    value = 0
    for y in mean:
        if x >= y:
            value = value + 1
```

I am basically wanting to iterate through each list so x[1] gets compared to mean[0], x[2] gets compared to mean [1], and x[3] gets compared to mean[2], and so on. Then this gets repeated again for the next list. So I know that the 'for y' in there means I am comparing x[0] with all of the y values, but I don't know how to change it to what I want it to do?

Secondly, I want 'value' to actually equal the first item in each list. So instead of value it is actually item1. Because I don't know what item1 will be I need to extract it from the list and then make it the variable, and I don't know how to do this. So in reality it would look like this:

```
items = [["item1", 5, 10, 8, 6], ["item2", 4, 6, 3, 9]]
mean = [5, 5, 5, 5]
for x in items[0]:
    *item1* = 0 (but this needs to be named from x[0]
    for y in mean:
        if x >= y:
            *item1* = *item1* + 1
```

So in the end I would want output to look something like this:

```
item1 = 4
item2 = 2
```

At a bit of a loss as to what to do so any help would be appreciated. Oh and please keep it simple I don't really know what I am doing.

Comment: Use indices, not direct iteration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Use a variable as a list name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324465/python-use-a-variable-as-a-list-name)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip`:

`zip` returns items on same index from the iterables passed to it.

Demo:

```
>>> item = items[0]
>>> zip(item[1:], mean)
[(5, 5), (10, 5), (8, 5), (6, 5)]
```

`zip` returns a list of tuples, for a memory efficient solution use `iterools.izip`.

**Code:**

```
for item in items:
    val = sum( x >= y for x,y in zip(item[1:], mean))
    # x>=y is either True or False and in python True == 1, False == 0
    print "{} = {}".format(item[0],val)
...     
item1 = 4
item2 = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this "one-liner":

```
ans = dict([(j[0],sum([1 for i,v in enumerate(j[1:]) if v>=mean[i]])) for j in items])
#{'item1': 4, 'item2': 2}

item1, item2 = ans['item1'], ans['item2']
```