# Generate list of objects named recursively

Tags: python, debugging

My goal is to get a list of Objects named <del>recursively</del> dynamically. This is the code I tried.
I want the `object_list` to be `[Object_0, Object_1, Object_2, Object_3, Object_4]`

```
object_list = []

class Object(object):  
    size = ""
    price = ""

def create_object_list(object_list):   
    for num in range(5):
        Object_%s = Object() %num  
        object_list.append(Object_%s)
    return object_list
```

This is the error:

```
Object_%s = Object() %num
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Comment: I think you mean dynamically, not recursively. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop

Comment: Perhaps you'd better tell us what is it you're trying to achieve. We could help you much better that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Use a variable as a list name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324465/python-use-a-variable-as-a-list-name)

Answer (score 0):

Having seen the comments on the page, the real answer is **just use a list and don't try and give the objects names to denote their place in the list**. What you are trying to do is an antipattern. You don't need to set the "name" of the object as if you want to access `object_n` you can get it via `objects[n]`. Additionally you can keep things simple use a `dict` or a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) instead of your custom class.

```
from random import random

objects = []

for i in range(5):
    obj = {'size': random(), 'price': random()}
    objects.append(obj)

print(objects[0])
print(objects[3]['size'])
print(objects[1]['price'])
```

For the specific error in the question:

You can't use `%` in a variable name as it is an [operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations). See here for what you can use in a name:

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

```
>>> variable_name = 1
>>> variable_%name = 2
  File "<input>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
>>>
```

There are several other problems in the code in your question that will probably bite you:

- Your `Object` has class variables and not instance variables.
- You are somehow mixing string and integers.
- You are not actually using recursion in your code (this is in most cases a good thing though).

Comment: What I'm trying to do is a kind of c++ array of structures(An structure on each cell). I thought this would be the way to do it in python.

Comment: You almost certainly want a `list` of `dicts` or a `dict` of `lists` or some other combination of built-in data structures. I suggest having a read of https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html Most Python code ends up looking extremely simple and boring, especially compared to C++ :)

Comment: @BlenderUser check the ctypes module, and the Structure class... Is this what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
exec("Object_%s = Object()" %num)
exec("object_list.append(Object_%s)" %num)
```

Because otherwise it looks like you are trying to format live lines of code and not strings.
That's the obvious error in your code - but otherwise I must agree with all others - if you don't have a good reason for creating variables - just use a dic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an `object_dict`:

```
object_dict = {}

class Object(object):
    size = ""
    price = ""

def create_object_list(object_dict):
    for num in range(5):
        object_dict["Object_{}".format(num)] = Object()
    return object_dict
```

If you need order for some reason use a collections.OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
object_dict = OrderedDict()
```

which will keep the order the object are created:

```
OrderedDict([('Object_0', <__main__.Object object at 0x7f05d4044390>), ('Object_1', <__main__.Object object at 0x7f05d3fd3710>), ('Object_2', <__main__.Object object at 0x7f05d3fd36d8>), ('Object_3', <__main__.Object object at 0x7f05d3fd3a90>), ('Object_4', <__main__.Object object at 0x7f05d273a278>)])
```

You can access each object by key:

```
print(object_dict["Object_0"])
<__main__.Object object at 0x7f05d4044390>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to dynamically create variable names which is not possible. The `%` operator only works for strings not identifiers. You probably want to use a list here of strings.

If you really want to create new variables dynamically you can use the `locals()` built-in function which contains a dictionary of local variables. You can for example use `locals()['object_%d' % num] = Object()`. The `globals()` function can be used if you want to create global variables.

Notice that even if you do this, you won't get a list of variable names when you print the list; you'll get a list of values.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do this:

```
class Object(object):
    def __init__(self, inst_id):
        self.name = "Object_%d" % inst_id 
        self.size = ""
        self.price = ""

def create_object_list(object_list):
    for num in range(6):
        object_list.append(Object(num))
    return object_list         


for x in create_object_list(object_list):
    print x.name

Object_0
Object_1
Object_2
Object_3
Object_4
Object_5
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have these five variables:

```
a = (1,2,3)
e = "a string"
i = 1.56
o = {'size':'small', 'price':'low'}
u = None
```

and a list grouping them:

```
them = [a,e,i,o,u]
```

You could have created this list dinamically this way:

```
same = [eval(_) for _ in 'aeiou']
print(same)
# [(1, 2, 3), 'a string', 1.56, {'price': 'low', 'size': 'small'}, None]
```

So, the list of variables you need to create can be done the same way:

```
object_list = [eval('Object_'+str(n)) for n in range(5)]
```

If the objects already exsist, you can use the variables inside your list, but to create the variables themselves dinamically, you could do:

```
for _ in ('Object_'+str(n)+'=None' for n in range(5)): # or '=...' any appropriate value
    exec(_)                                            # it could be a call to your Object()

print(objcet_list)
# [None, None, None, None, None]
```